# What is the best cacher for drupal (Boost, xcache or varnish)?

Tags: drupal, caching, boost, varnish, xcache

What is the best caching method (cacher) for Drupal, taking in consideration logged in and anonymous users? is it Boost, XCache,or Varnish? I need a comparison between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Varnish** is output cache and saves more than 50% queries to Mysql server. also it allows for a grace period to serve expired cache objects if you experience failure of your back-end
**xCache** it caches your PHP code on-the-fly transparently saving on compile time next time the same code is run. it is used for Opcode cache + storing Datastore
**Boost** provides static page caching for Drupal enabling a very significant performance and scalability boost for sites that receive mostly anonymous traffic

Comment: Varnish & Boost are very similar; Boost is easy to install, Varnish can be faster. For 99% of sites out there Boost or Varnish will provide the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

Varnish is super good as frontend server -- running Drupal site under proxy server. Varnish should not run with boost.

Memcache should also used to reduce alot of query to mysql.